# Mysql Random Communications Link Failure when connecting via JDBC from Data Fusion

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have pipelines on a Data Fusion instance which connects & fetches data from Mysql and inserts i into Big Query. The problem is I randomly receive this error

```
Communications link failure The last packet successfully received from the server was 20,103 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 20,104 milliseconds ago
```

And when I say random, it is like 2 pipelines run at the same time when succeeds and other one fails. When I just re-run the failed pipeline without any changes, it just works, so there is no pattern.

Here is the full error :

````
Application diagnostics message: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted. at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:105) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1077) at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414) at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1075) at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(JavaPairRDD.scala:833) at 
io.cdap.cdap.etl.spark.batch.RDDUtils.saveHadoopDataset(RDDUtils.java:58) at io.cdap.cdap.etl.spark.batch.RDDUtils.saveUsingOutputFormat(RDDUtils.java:47) at io.cdap.cdap.etl.spark.batch.SparkBatchSinkFactory.writeFromRDD(SparkBatchSinkFactory.java:198) at 
io.cdap.cdap.etl.spark.batch.BaseRDDCollection$1.run(BaseRDDCollection.java:238) at io.cdap.cdap.etl.spark.SparkPipelineRunner.runPipeline(SparkPipelineRunner.java:344) at io.cdap.cdap.etl.spark.batch.BatchSparkPipelineDriver.run(BatchSparkPipelineDriver.java:235) at io.cdap.cdap.app.runtime.spark.SparkTransactional$2.run(SparkTransactional.java:236) at io.cdap.cdap.app.runtime.spark.SparkTransactional.execute(SparkTransactional.java:208) at io.cdap.cdap.app.runtime.spark.SparkTransactional.execute(SparkTransactional.java:138) at 
io.cdap.cdap.app.runtime.spark.AbstractSparkExecutionContext.execute(AbstractSparkExecutionContext.scala:231) at io.cdap.cdap.app.runtime.spark.SerializableSparkExecutionContext.execute(SerializableSparkExecutionContext.scala:63) at io.cdap.cdap.app.runtime.spark.DefaultJavaSparkExecutionContext.execute(DefaultJavaSparkExecutionContext.scala:94) at io.cdap.cdap.api.Transactionals.execute(Transactionals.java:63) at io.cdap.cdap.etl.spark.batch.BatchSparkPipelineDriver.run(BatchSparkPipelineDriver.java:162) at 
io.cdap.cdap.app.runtime.spark.SparkMainWrapper$.main(SparkMainWrapper.scala:88) at io.cdap.cdap.app.runtime.spark.SparkMainWrapper.main(SparkMainWrapper.scala) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:732) Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 9)
*** executor 3): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows at 
org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:162) at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$write$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:88) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:505) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:508) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by: java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:240) at
io.cdap.plugin.db.batch.source.DataDrivenETLDBInputFormat$1.nextKeyValue(DataDrivenETLDBInputFormat.java:142) at 
io.cdap.cdap.etl.spark.io.TrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(TrackingRecordReader.java:47) at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:247) at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37) at 
scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491) at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:135) at 
org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1473) at 
org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:134) ... 9 more Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet successfully received from the server was 20,102 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 20,102 milliseconds ago. at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ServerPreparedState
ment.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:633) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:417) at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.MySQLDataDrivenDBRecordReader.executeQuery(MySQLDataDrivenDBRecordReader.java:49) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:228) ... 21 more Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet successfully received from the server was 20,102 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 20,102 milliseconds ago. at 

sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) at 
com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) at 
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:546) at 
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:710) at 
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:649) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:136) at 
com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.sendCommand(NativeSession.java:311) at com.mysql.cj.ServerPreparedQuery.sendExecutePacket(ServerPreparedQuery.java:337) at com.mysql.cj.ServerPreparedQuery.serverExecute(ServerPreparedQuery.java:207) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:631) ... 25 more Caused by: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out at 
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) at
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) at 
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) at 
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:464) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:68) at 
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1346) at 

sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$300(SSLSocketImpl.java:73) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:962) at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:64) at 
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:52) at
 com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:41) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:54) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:44) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:540) ... 32 more Driver stacktrace: at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2304) at
 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2253) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2252) at 
scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62) at 
scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55) at 
scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2252) at 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1124) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1124) at
 scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407) at 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1124) at 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2491) at 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2433) at 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2422) at 
org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:902) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2204) at
 org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2225) at 
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2257) at 
org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:83) ... 28 more Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows at 
org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:162) at 
org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$write$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:88) at 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:505) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:508) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by: java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:240) at io.cdap.plugin.db.batch.source.DataDrivenETLDBInputFormat$1.nextKeyValue(DataDrivenETLDBInputFormat.java:142) at 
io.cdap.cdap.etl.spark.io.TrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(TrackingRecordReader.java:47) at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:247) at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491) at 
scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491) at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:135) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1473) at 
org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:134) ... 9 more Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet successfully received from the server was 20,102 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 20,102 milliseconds ago. at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:633) at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:417) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.MySQLDataDrivenDBRecordReader.executeQuery(MySQLDataDrivenDBRecordReader.java:49) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:228) ... 21 more Caused by: 
com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet successfully received from the server was 20,102 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 20,102 milliseconds ago. at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at 

sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) at 

com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:546) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:710) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:649) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:136) at 

com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.sendCommand(NativeSession.java:311) at com.mysql.cj.ServerPreparedQuery.sendExecutePacket(ServerPreparedQuery.java:337) at 
com.mysql.cj.ServerPreparedQuery.serverExecute(ServerPreparedQuery.java:207) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:631) ... 25 more Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) at 
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:464) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:68) at 
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1346) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$300(SSLSocketImpl.java:73) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:962) at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) at 
com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:64) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHe
ader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:52) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:41) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:54) at 
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:44) at 
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:540)```
````

Comment: _"Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"_

Comment: Yes the thing is another pipeline which reads data from Mysql at the same moment does not have this issue. Or we never have this issue when we connect to Mysql with external clients like DBeaver and such.

Comment: @MeteHan Does this [article](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/support/troubleshooting) by Google help you to solve your problem.Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hey @kiranmathew thanks a lot for taking time to respond however there is nothing related to my issue in this article.

Comment: @MeteHan It seems to be an internal issue. If you have a support plan, I would recommend you to raise a ticket with [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support). If not, create a thread in Google’s Issue Tracker using this [template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659). You can also STAR the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).